# Как найти только те HTML элементы, в которых есть определенный элемент?

Tags: html, python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Есть кусок кода HTML страницы которую я парсю:

```
<td>
  <a class="soup" href="link">Борщ</a>
</td>
<td>
  <a class="soup" href="link">Рассольник</a>
  <br>
    <img src="/any.gif">
  </br>
</td>
<td>
  <a class="soup" href="link">Грибной</a>
</td>
<td>
  <a class="soup" href="link">Щи</a>
  <br>
    <img src="/any.gif">
  </br>
</td>
<td>
  <a class="soup" href="link">Молочный</a>
</td>
```

Вопрос: как собрать все только те, под которыми есть `<br> <img>`?
Как собрать все `<td>` в которых есть `<br> <img>`? (с помощью *BeautifulSoup*)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Comment: Так вообще не бывает.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это что, не решаемая задача средствами bs?

Comment: Это некорректный html. Ни один браузер так вложить не позволить. Про bs не знаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ты что такое говоришь? Это реальный рабочий код со страницы.

Comment: `<br/>` это пустой элемент в html—он ничего не может содержать. BeautifulSoup конечно может по произвольным критериям искать.

Comment: @jfs Я пробовал использовать soup.find('img', {'src': '/any.gif'}).findPreviousSibling('a'), но так он находит только один <a>, а мне нужны все

Comment: если результат find вас устраивает, можно find_all использовать

Comment: @jfs когда использую find_all, то получаю ошибку ResultSet object has no attribute 'findPreviousSiblings'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: подумайте: если вы знаете как получить результат для одного элемента, то как получить список результатов из списка входных значений? Почему вы ожидаете, что `список.атрибут` вернёт значения атрибута для элементов списка? Вместо этого попробуйте `результат = [элемент.атрибут for элемент in список]`

Comment: @jfs Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70716/discussion-between-windows-eight-and-jfs).

Answer (score 0):

```
for img in soup.find_all('img', {'src': '/any.gif'}):
   if img.findPreviousSibling('a') is not None:
     a=img.findPreviousSibling('a')
     print(a)
```

Ответ с [англ. stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950628/beautifulsoup-how-to-find-only-tags-containing-the-tag/47951173#47951173)